# How to create an exe file with local database attach ? (Visual Studio C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, exe

I would like to create an `.exe` file with database `.mdf` file attach. I try to run the `.exe` file on a client computer. It produces this error:

[image]

My SQL connection code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\zy\source\repos\Automation\Automation\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=Truee");
```

Solution Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Which SQL Server version you're using? Your DB connection string seems a little bit off, missing both `Data Source` and `AttachDbFilename` parameters.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Hi, i think i accidentally deleted the string. I replace the string already. It is a local DB.

Comment: the error clearly states that you don't have the LocalDB components installed.

Comment: @Claies How to install it on client when client click on the exe file ? Do i have to manually installed in client computer ?

Comment: LocalDB requires SQL Express.  You'll either have to install it separately, or package it with the installer for your app.  There are **hundreds** of articles on how to do this.

Comment: @Claies  is this the correct SQL express installation ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOpgvtHfYjY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem indicates requested LocalDB instance requires SQL Server Express instance to run properly, and the machine where executable file started doesn't have running SQL Server Express instance.

If you want to run SQL Server Express together with application start event, make sure SQL Server LocalDB component(s) included in prerequisities by using `Project -> [ProjectName] Properties -> Publish` menu and look for `Prerequisities` section like the following:

[image]

The `LocalDB` option depends on which SQL Server version you're using, this will download & install SQL Server Express instance to any client machines which at the time of installation doesn't have SQL Server instance installed.

Additionaly, ensure that database files (both .mdf and .ldf) are included in `Application Files` section:

[image: Application Files Lookup]

Finally, you may adjust the connection string to be more general by using `|DataDirectory|` in case the application installed in different folder, like example below:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Automation\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

**Note 1:** Consider to use a resource file or `app.config` to include LocalDB connection string for efficiency.

**Note 2:** If you don't want to include SQL Server Express LocalDB instance as prerequisities, make sure you include it separately in the installation package.

Comment: Hi, Tetsuya I have try your solution and i am having this error. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share. Any chance that this may relate to the SqlConnection ?

Comment: I solved it by deleting Automation from \Automation\Database1.mdf